# CUDA fmaf function

Tags: optimization, cuda

I am trying to optimize a CUDA code. I replaced expression

`result = x*y+z`

with

`result = fmaf(x,y,z)`

But, it gives an error -  ***CUDA error: kernel launch failure (7): too many resources requested for launch***

Comment: I'm wondering if the CUDA compiler will try to automatically perform those kind of optimizations for you, see [FMAD on CUDA](http://choorucode.com/2012/05/12/fmad-on-cuda/).

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: On sm_1x platforms, there is no hardware support for fmaf() and the function is implemented by fairly hefty emulation code. This will increase register usage, which can lead to an "out of resources" error. nvcc defaults to compilation for an sm_10 target. If your GPU is not in fact an sm_1x device, I suggest compiling the code with the appropriate -arch flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JackOLantern indicated, it's  likely the device code compiler will make this kind of optimization for you.  You can compare the two cases to see what kind of code has been emitted by using:

```
nvcc -ptx -arch...  mycode.cu
```

to see what kind of PTX code got emitted in each case, or:

```
cuobjdump -sass myapp
```

to see what kind of SASS (device machine code) got emitted in each case.

You haven't supplied any actual code, but the "too many resources requested for launch" in the context of this question is most likely due to requesting too many registers per threadblock ((registers per thread) * (threads per block) should be less than the maximum registers allowable per block, i.e. per multiprocessor).

You can determine the maximum registers allowable per block for your device using the `deviceQuery` sample code or from the [programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications). (registers per multiprocessor)

You can find out how many registers per thread the compiler is using by specifying:

```
-Xptxas -v
```

as additional command-line switches when compiling your code.

You can use the [launch bounds](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#launch-bounds) qualifier to instruct the compiler to use fewer registers per thread.